# Working with files in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, file-io

I'm creating an application in OpenGL for displaying sine and cosine functions, everything works fine, but now I have to write and read data from a file, I know how to work with them but when I run my application it doesn't work. I want to write the information into a binary file and then read it. I know how to do this, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

This is my structure:

```
struct graphi
{
    int id;
    int amplitude;
    char function;
    float frequency;
};
```

And this is my function (`f` is a `FILE*`):

```
void menu(struct graphi g)
{
    int numGrap = 0;
    f = fopen("data.txt", "wb");    

    printf("How many graphics would you like to display?: ");
    scanf("%d", &numGrap);

    for(int i=0; i<numGrap; i++)
    {
        printf("-------------------------------Graphic %d: ", i+1);

        g.id=i;

        printf("\nEnter the amplitude: ");
        scanf("%d", &g.amplitude);

        printf("\nEnter the function, sin->'s' o cos->'c': ");
        scanf("%s", g.function);

        printf("\nEnter the frequency: ");
        scanf("%f", &g.frequency); 

        fseek(f, i * sizeof(g), SEEK_SET );
        fwrite(&g, sizeof(g), 1, f);

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    fclose(f);  
}
```

Like I said, I can draw the graphics, I have the functions, and everything works, my problem is when I work with files, and I'm working with binary files.

Comment: `scanf("%s", g.function);` this shouldn't work.

Comment: Even though your program is based on OpenGL, the issue in question hardly seems to have any relation with the API. Please be more specific in the future when categorising your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be reading a string into function, which is a minimum of 2 characters when you include the null terminator. You got undefined behaviour there for starters. function either needs to be a suitible size array, with a length limit on your scanf statement if you want any kind of safty, or a char can be assigned with = or an enum is likely better given the situation. It would also be helpful to see the code youre using to read the binary. In the name of making the struct naturally aligned Id put the float before the char as well.